# How to take a picture wihout using surface area in Android Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android

I have developed an Android app for Gingerbread OS version.
Now I am trying to customize it to ICS version but I have one problem.
The app using the camera class to capture a picture without display a surface area.

```
public boolean TakePicture()
{
    if (mCamera == null)
    {
        Log.e(mLogTag, "Camera wasn't loaded.");
        return false;
    }


    // this doesn't really show the frames on the screen without define a SurfaceHolder.
    mCamera.startPreview();

    // actually take the picture.
    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);

    return true;
}
```

When it calls the TakePicture method a Run-Time Exception is being throw with this message:
"takePicture Failed".
In Gingerbread version it works.

Comment: It shouldn't work in Gingerbread either.

Comment: Using the `Camera` without a `SurfaceView` never used to work. The theory was it was for privacy reasons -- a `SurfaceView` of some minimum size was needed so the user knew that the camera was in operation.